# how to iterate through two arrays simultaneously with lodash

Tags: lodash

I have

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
B = [3,5,9]
I want to get an array C containing the last elements < than elements in B, like
C = [2,4,7], by using Lodash
```

I tried

```
C=_.map(A, a = (v) -> v == _.findLast(A, b = (v) -> v < _.forEach(B, c = (v) -> v==v)))
```

which does not work. Above I used coffeescript instead of javascript, but please reply with either, I want a solution using lodash, without explicit looping through B elements, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [forEach](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#forEach) is redundant, and just returns the original collection:

```js
const A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
const B = [3,5,9]

// C = [2,4,7], by using Lodash

const result = _.map(B, n => _.findLast(A, m => m < n));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes, correct, in coffeescript:   C = _.map(B, m = (v) -> _.findLast(A, n = (w) -> w < v))

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you want a lodash soultion, but just in case you were curious here is a way to get your desired array using vanilla ES6:

```js
const A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const B = [3, 5, 9];
const C = findEls(A, B);

function findEls(A, B) {
  const copy = [...A].reverse(); //Copy since reverse is an in-place operation
  return B.map(b => {
    return copy.find(a => a < b);
  });
}

console.log(C);
```